# Geo IP Module for nginx

Tags: nginx, geoip

On my nginx server, I am going to use more than one of the geo ip databases (one for country+city and another one for isp or organization). I could not find a module for nginx and/or pecl to get more than one of these databases to run.

The database provider is not going to publish a single DB with all the data in one file), so it looks like i am lost.

http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Nginx_and_PHP-FPM_Installation seems to work with one DB only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with the standard built-in GeoIP nginx module:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html

```
geoip_country  CountryCity.dat;
geoip_city     CountryCity.dat;
geoip_org      Organization.dat;
```

Comment: maybe i missed something, but i still can not find the ISP.dat

Comment: Have you got any problem with `geoip_org ISP.dat;`?

Comment: Depending on which database file you have specified in the `geoip_org` directive you will have Organization, Domain, ISP or AS number in the `$geoip_org` nginx variable.

Comment: the database provider delivers 2 separate DBs to me, one Organization and another with ISP. I do not really want to switch between the 2 beccause i need details from both DB sources.

Comment: You can use `geoip_org` with the one DB file and PHP module with the another. It looks like a hack, but I hope nginx will support separate settings for this case. You can fill a feature request at http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ (it may speed up things a bit).

Comment: there seem to be some forks with the additional db sources in Russion developer forums. the alternative is the pecl module. i will try both. thanks for the tips!

Comment: i cannot get the value of country code, im stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282599/nginx-geoip-module-undefined-country-code